# Why is this code outOfBound?

Tags: c, arrays

Here is a problem I met the other day in a interview, would someone tell me the "truth" behind this "simple" code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[]={1,2,3};
    for(int i=0; i<=3; i++){
        a[i]=0;
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is, could you add more details?

Answer (score 1):

Everything will be right if <= is replaced by < as it is causing array out of bound index error and will print value 
0
1 
2 
3
although the value of the array content will be 0 every time

Answer (score 0):

The loop variable `i` takes on values 0, 1, 2, and 3. Unfortunately, 3 is an out-of-bounds index for array `a`, which only has length 3 (legal indices 0, 1, and 2). To avoid an out-of-bounds array access, the loop control should be

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
```

Note the use of `<` instead of `<=`. As an interview question, the goal was to test whether you noticed this very common kind of [off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error).

Comment: The man also asked what is the worst result of this code, and i do not know how to describe, would you explain something more?  Thanks.

Comment: OH.....Thanks for the `off-by-one error` link, i am learning, thanks a lot.

Comment: @true2009fans - The effect of writing 0 to the memory location just past `a` is totally unpredictable. It depends entirely on what happens to be in memory just past `a`, which depends on the compiler and the hardware architecture, among other things. It could range from no effect at all, to a crash, to handing control over to code over which you have no control. In fact, buffer overflows like this are a prime attack vector for hackers.